# Linux kernel driver: IRQ triggered or timeout

Tags: linux, timeout, kernel, driver, irq

In a linux kernel driver, I would like to repeat indefinitely the following sequence:

- at time T, a hardware IRQ is enabled
- between time T and T + "around" 15ms, the IRQ callback can be reached if the IRQ is triggered. I say around because I'm not using an RT kernel and if it's 14 or 16ms, it's fine. In the IRQ callback, I need to write down get cpu_clock(0) and call wake_up_interruptible. The timeout needs to be killed. The whole process needs to be started again within 5ms.
- if by T + "around" 15ms, the IRQ has not been triggered, I need to execute some other code. The IRQ should be disabled then. The whole process needs to be started again within 5ms.

Therefore, by T + "around" 20ms, in worst case, the whole process needs to be started again.

Note that if the IRQ is physically triggered at 18ms, too bad, "I missed the train". I will catch another hardware trigger at the next sequence.

While testing, I was doing something along the following pseudo-code:

```
INIT_DELAYED_WORK(&priv->work, driver_work);
INIT_DELAYED_WORK(&priv->timeout, driver_timeout);
request_irq(priv->irq, driver_interrupt, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING, "my_irq", priv);
```

then:

```
queue_delayed_work(priv->workq, &priv->work, 0ms);

static void driver_work(struct work_struct *work) {
    queue_delayed_work(priv->workq, &priv->timeout, 15ms);
    priv->interruptCalled = 0;
    enable_irq(priv->irq);
}
```

Then:

```
static irqreturn_t driver_interrupt(int irq, void *_priv) {
    disable_irq_nosync(priv->irq);
    priv->interruptCalled = 1;
    cancel_delayed_work(&priv->timeout);
    priv->stamp = cpu_clock(0);
    wake_up_interruptible(&driver_wait);
    queue_delayed_work(priv->workq, &priv->work, 5ms);
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
```

}

And:

```
static void driver_timeout(struct work_struct *work) {
    if (priv->interruptCalled == 0) {
        disable_irq_nosync(priv->irq);
        //Do other small cleanup
        queue_delayed_work(priv->workq, &priv->work, 5ms);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a robust but simple driver. Is this a proper implementation? How can I improve this implementation?

Comment: The cancel_delayed_work generates "WARNING: at kernel/timer.c:1061 del_timer_sync+0x44/0x64()" from time to time. How can I avoid that?

Comment: This warning corresponds to WARN_ON(in_irq()); It seems that deleting a timer from an irq context is not a good idea.

Comment: I have put "cancel_delayed_work(&priv->timeout);" as the first line of "driver_work". No more warning and I think that the logic is not damaged because priv->interruptCalled 'protects' in case the timeout is triggered even in the case the IRQ has been triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: the problem is that queue_delayed_work is based on jiffies. Or 5ms is not possible as HZ=100 (1 jiffy = 10ms). HR timer brought a good solution.